# nvidia-cuda-toolkit version 8.0.44 ppa?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I am looking for a ppa for the latest nvidia cuda version 8.0.44
I prefer to use the Ubuntu package nvidia-cuda-toolkit instead of the collection of packages supplied by nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an old question here, but for future reference.  If you need a specific version of cuda it is actually very easy to install CUDA for specific version of Ubuntu LTS releases.  You just need to make sure you have the Ubuntu default repo cuda **REMOVED**.

You can check the version of the nvidia-cuda-toolkit by running this command.

```
nvcc --version
```

output

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA
>   Corporation Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017 Cuda compilation
>   tools, **release 8.0, V8.0.61**

After you successfully install using the .deb file provided by Nvidia make sure you add the directory to your file path so it works with anything that may be looking for it like this.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```